# Quoting Parameters > Triple quotes to single quotes

Tags: python, pandas

TLDR; My question is how do I read in a file that has triple quotes wrapped around each item? Drop 2 quotes but keep 1 quotes around the items and then download it as a new csv.

Sample Dataset:

I have a dataset in a csv format.
This is what it looks like when I open it with Text Editor.

| pizza_topping_id | customer_email |
| --- | --- |
| """1""" | """junglehouse1@yahoo.com""" |

Ideal output (one quote instead of 3):

| pizza_topping_id | customer_email |
| --- | --- |
| "1" | "junglehouse1@yahoo.com" |

### What I've tried using Jupyter Notebook:

#### Attempt 1

I read in the file with (keeping in mind that it's wrapped in triple quotes)

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/TEST.csv')
```

This generates a dataframe with single quotes.

I then generate a new csv with the new dataframe wrapped in single quotes using the below code:

```
df3.to_csv('~/Downloads/TEST_V2.csv', header=True, index=False, line_terminator='\r\n')
```

However, when I open it up in TextEditor it still is triple quotes.
After doing all that the file still looks like this:

| pizza_topping_id | customer_email |
| --- | --- |
| """1""" | """junglehouse1@yahoo.com""" |

So I think to myself okay, maybe it's a parameter I need to throw into the to_csv to keep the single quotes so I try the below attempt

#### Attempt 2

```
df3.to_csv('~/Downloads/TEST_V2.csv', header=True, index=False, encoding ='UTF8', line_terminator='\r\n')
```

My result when I reopen this new file (TEST_V2) is that it's still in triple quotes.

Comment: This can be difficult to keep track of.  If you want a string with one character, `1`, that would be encoded in a CSV as `"1"` and would be read back as `1`.  But if you want the string in your program to have three characters, `"1"`, then that has to be encoded in the CSV file as `"""1"""`.  It looks to me like your CSV file was initially created incorrectly.

Comment: Hey Tim! Correct, my CSV was initially created incorrectly. I'm trying to fix it and drop 2 quotes so it's only wrapped in single quotes like this "this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pandas documentation, [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) have keyword argument `doublequote` which defaults to true. It represents quotes in fields as two quotes, `"string"` stored as `""string""`. These are then wrapped by pandas with another set of quotes, resulting in the final triple quotes. In addition, there is `quoting` which takes a constant from module `csv`. To keep the single quoted strings, this would need to be set to `csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

To clean the data, `read_csv()` has argument `converters` available, which accepts a dict mapping column name/index => transformation functions.
To change the triple quotes to single, the function could be:

```
def cleaner(s):
    return s.strip('"')
```

Setting up the dict for affected columns with a generator:

```
converters = {
    i: cleaner
    for i in ('pizza_topping_id','customer_email')
}
```

And updating the `read_csv()` call

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/TEST.csv', converters=converters)
```

After being saved, the csv can be loaded without the argument.

I created a working  example, but it currently outputs fields without quotes. Messing around with the `quoting` argument for both functions, the headers would get quoted as well, the id gets converted to a float, among other side-effects.

The cleanest way I have found so far to ensure single quotes in only those fields is modifying the cleaning lambda to `'"' + s.strip('"') + '"'` and setting `quoting` to `csv.QUOTE_NONE`, but this could affect your other columns as well.

The example:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from sys import stdout
import pandas as pd


file_data = (
    'pizza_topping_id,customer_email\r\n'
    '"""1""","""junglehouse1@yahoo.com"""\r\n')
fake_file = StringIO(file_data)
print("\nInput:")
print(file_data)


# initial cleaning parse
def cleaner(s):
    return s.strip('"')
converters = {
    i: cleaner
    for i in ('pizza_topping_id', 'customer_email')
}
df = pd.read_csv(fake_file, converters=converters)
print("\nParsed DF:")
print(df)


# cleaned output
output = df.to_csv(header=True, index=False)
print("\nRaw File Output:")
print(output)


# reloading df
fake_file = StringIO(output)
df = pd.read_csv(fake_file)
print("\nNew DF:")
print(df)


# resaving csv
output = df.to_csv(header=True, index=False)
print("\nNew File Output:")
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what happened was the data originally had no quotes (e.g. `1`), the original CSV had all fields quoted (e.g. `"1"`), but then someone loaded it without using quoting (corrupting the data into `"1"`) then saved it with quoting (resulting in the triple-quotes).

So you can just do the process in reverse: load with quoting (which you've already done), then save without, using the `quoting` parameter of [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
import csv
print(df.to_csv(index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE))
```

Result:

```
pizza_topping_id,customer_email
"1","junglehouse1@yahoo.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the quotations. Added back the quotations and saved the CSV in with the correct quoting parameters

Assume df2 is the sample file loaded into a dataframe:

1. Remove extra quotes

   ```
   for i, col in enumerate(df2.columns):
       df2.iloc[:, i] = df2.iloc[:, i].str.replace('"', '')
   ```
2. Add back in quotes

   ```
   all_cols = list(df2)

   for i in all_cols:
       df2[i] = '"' + df2[i] + '"'
   ```
3. Write to CSV with correct params

   ```
   df2.to_csv('~/Downloads/final_test.csv', header=True, index=False, quoting=3, encoding='UTF8', line_terminator='\r\n')
   ```

Comment: What's `3`? Is that `csv.QUOTE_NONE`? The value isn't documented, so you should use the name instead in case it changes. It's also easier to read.

Answer (score -2):

Here's code to remove the triple quotes in a proper way.

```
import csv

out = cvs.writer(open('revised.csv','w'))
for row in csv.reader(open('~/Downloads/TEST.csv')):
    row = [r.strip('"') for r in row]
    out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hey Tim thanks for the response! Trying to run this now and weird I'm getting a FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Downloads/TEST_V2.csv'

Comment: @Maggie Looks like Tim just got the input and output backwards. `~/Downloads/TEST.csv` is the input, right? Use that instead.

Comment: Hey! So I used the code, fixed the mistake when I was explicit about my path, but...the output is a doc that has no quotes at all unfortunately.

Comment: The quotes are optional in a CSV file unless the field contains quotes or commas.  However, the `csv` doc page would have showed you that adding `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` to the `csv.writer` call would force all fields to be quoted.

Comment: for i, col in enumerate(TEST.columns):
    TEST.iloc[:, i] = TEST.iloc[:, i].str.replace('"', '') 

I just use this to strip it